The type initializer for 'Syncfusion.PdfToImageConverter.PdfiumNative' threw an exception."
I'm encountering an error while working with the ASP.NET Core PDF Viewer Web Service example provided by Syncfusion. The error message I'm seeing is:
"The type initializer for 'Syncfusion.PdfToImageConverter.PdfiumNative' threw an exception."
I've followed the instructions provided in the GitHub repository (https://github.com/SyncfusionExamples/EJ2-PDFViewer-WebServices/tree/main/ASP.NET%20Core/PdfViewerWebService_8.0) to set up the project, but I'm unable to resolve this issue.
Here's some additional information about my environment:

I'm using the ASP.NET Core PDF Viewer Web Service example from the SyncfusionExamples repository.
I've followed all the setup instructions provided in the README.md file of the repository.
The error occurs consistently when trying to open the document.

I've verified that all the necessary dependencies are installed and referenced correctly, but the error persists. Can someone provide guidance on how to troubleshoot and fix this issue? Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Solution 1:
We have already included documentation on how to resolve this type of issue in our documentation. Please find the provided documentation below.
Documentation: https://ej2.syncfusion.com/aspnetcore/documentation/pdfviewer/how-to/resolve-pdfium-issue
Solution 2:
We recommended to use the "Syncfusion.EJ2.PdfViewer.AspNet.Core" Nuget package which is compatible with Windows, Linux and OSX platforms and If you are facing the reported issue in the production environment, Please provide the following details. This will be helpful for us to analyze further and provide the details.
Hosted environment (Windows, Linux, or Mac), the steps for deploying the application (using Docker or any other method).
Whether you are rendering the component inside a docker container.
If possible, provide the sample in which the reported issue is occurred.
